# How can I get this string replacement in hebrew to work?

Tags: c#, .net, string, replace

I would like to replace this placeholders in a hebrew string.
But unfortunately the string replacement does not work. It looks like the placeholder string cannot be found at all within the hebrew string.

```
    [Test]
    public void Fancy_placeholder_should_be_replaced()
    {
        const string input = "(השדה @%1$ קצר מדי (@%2$ תווים לפחות";
        const string expected = "(השדה {0} קצר מדי ({1} תווים לפחות";

        var dummy = input.Replace("%2$@", "{1}");
        dummy = dummy.Replace("%1$@", "{0}");

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, dummy);
    }
```

How can I make replacement work here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763476/ignoring-hebrew-vowels-when-comparing-strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the right-to-left issue that messes up the results, in specific, it is the "@" char.
modify your function to:

```
public void Fancy_placeholder_should_be_replaced()
    {
        const string input = "(השדה @%1$ קצר מדי (@%2$ תווים לפחות";
        const string expected = "(השדה {0} קצר מדי ({1} תווים לפחות";

        var formatted = input.Replace("@%2$", "{1}");
        formatted = formatted.Replace("@%1$", "{0}");

        bool same2 = expected == formatted;
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, formatted);
    }
```

And tada! it works...

Comment: The @ is not the cause, `input.IndexOf("@")` returns 6, which is correct. Instead `input.IndexOf("%1$")` returns 7, where in my opinion should return -1, since it is right-to-left it would be more consistent for `input.IndexOf("$1%")` to return 7, because that is what the sequence if from right to left. I assume @ is commonly accepted in the Hebrew language, while $,1 and % aren't and therefor counted from left-to-right, hence % = index 7, 1 = 8 and $ = 9.

Comment: Actually, I am a hebrew speaker, and all of the '1@%2$' characters are common in hebrew as they are in english... The problem is that when you type any character, it aligns rtl, as you would have expected, except for the "@" character. I guess it is for better displaying of email addresses, go figure... You can see an example for that if you try to highlight the following text from left to right character by character: "1%ש2$@"

Comment: Hmmm now it makes sense, so everything in connection to the @ will be displayed left-to-right. Just to satisfy my curiosity, how are phone numbers displayed, left-to-right or right-to-left?

Comment: Phone numbers, and numbers in general, are displayed left to right.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing that much of the Hebrew language, I do know they read right to left. 
Presumably, `%1$` are not recognized as "Hebrew characters". Just check `dummy.IndexOf("%1$")`. It will give you 7, which is the position directly after the first `@` from the right. So, just to jump to the conclusion:

```
    var dummy = input.Replace("@%2$", "{1}");
    dummy = dummy.Replace("@%1$", "{0}");
```